# Printing elements in a linked list queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, queue

I have the following code in python. My question is how do you print each element in the linked queue? I know that I will have to make a `__repr__` or `__str__` function but I am unsure how to implement it. Thanks.

```
class LinkedQueue :
    class _Node :
        def __init__(self, element, next):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next


        def get_elements():
            return self._element

        def set_elements(num):
            self._element = num    

    def __init__(self) :
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self) :
        return self._size

    def is_empty(self) :
        return self._size == 0

    def first(self) :
        if self.is_empty() :
            raise Empty('Queue is empty')
        return self._head._element

    def dequeue(self) :
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Queue is empty')
        answer = self._head._element
        self._head = self._head._next
        self._size -= 1
        if self.is_empty() :
            self._tail = None
        return answer

    def enqueue(self, e) :
        newest = self._Node(e,None)
        if self.is_empty() :
            self._head = newest
        else :
            self._tail._next = newest
        self._tail = newest
        self._size += 1

class Empty(Exception) :
    pass
```

Comment: Have you  looked at just using a [python list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and the `append()` and `pop()` methods?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want the repr to look like, but here's one way. We give the `_Node` class a simple `__repr__` that just returns the repr of the element, and to build the repr for a `LinkedQueue` instance we walk the linked list, storing the repr of each `Node` into a list. We can then call `.join` on that list to make the repr for the `LinkedQueue`.

```
class Empty(Exception): 
    pass

class LinkedQueue: 
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, element, _next=None):
            self._element = element
            self._next = _next

        def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self._element)

    def __init__(self): 
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self): 
        return self._size

    def __repr__(self):
        lst = []
        head = self._head
        while head is not None:
            lst.append(repr(head))
            head = head._next
        return 'Queue({})'.format(", ".join(lst))

    def is_empty(self): 
        return self._size == 0

    def first(self): 
        if self.is_empty(): 
            raise Empty('Queue is empty')
        return self._head._element

    def dequeue(self): 
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Queue is empty')
        answer = self._head._element
        self._head = self._head._next
        self._size -= 1
        if self.is_empty(): 
            self._tail = None
        return answer

    def enqueue(self, e): 
        newest = self._Node(e)
        if self.is_empty(): 
            self._head = newest
        else: 
            self._tail._next = newest
        self._tail = newest
        self._size += 1

# test

q = LinkedQueue()
for u in 'abcd':
    q.enqueue(u)
    print(len(q))

print(q)

while not q.is_empty():
    print(q.first(), q.dequeue())
```

**output**

```
1
2
3
4
Queue('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
a a
b b
c c
d d
```

---

I got rid of the getter & setter method in `Node`, since you don't use them, and we don't normally write getters & setters like that in Python. See the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) in the docs.

FWIW, I would make `Node` a separate class (or get rid of it entirely), rather than nesting it in `LinkedQueue`. I guess it doesn't hurt to nest it, but nested class definitions aren't often used in Python.

BTW, the [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is a very efficient double-ended queue. For simple queues and stacks, it's generally faster than `list`. But I guess this `LinkedQueue` class is for an exercise in implementing linked lists in Python, so `collections.deque` isn't currently relevant for you. ;)